# How to set Storyboard.SetTargetProperty in Code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to convert XAML Storyboard to code behind Storyboard. But I get an exception

```
Cannot resolve all property references in the property path
  '(UIElement.RenderTransform).(myTransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)'.
  Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
```

I searched several websites but they also do this the same way. I don`t understand where I am going wrong.

XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="r1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.828"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.828"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="r1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="8.621"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="8.621"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

C# Code:

```
  public void myAnimation(Rectangle myRectangle)
    {
        this.UnregisterName(myRectangle.Name);
        ScaleTransform myScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        TranslateTransform myTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myScaleTransform);
        myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myTranslateTransform);
        myRectangle.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
        this.RegisterName(myRectangle.Name, myTransformGroup);

        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame myEasingDoubleKeyFrame = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, myRectangle.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(0);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 1;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(0.4);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 0.828;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(1);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 0.828;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, myRectangle.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(0);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 0;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(0.4);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = -17.5;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(1);
        myEasingDoubleKeyFrame.Value = 165.5;
        myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(myEasingDoubleKeyFrame);

        myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

        myStoryboard.Begin(myRectangle);

    }
```

I guess the problem is in **Storyboard.SetTargetProperty**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem using this line.

```
new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY")
```

thank`s everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `PropertyPath` like this:

```
new PropertyPath("(0).(1)[0].(2)", UIElement.RenderTransformProperty, TransformGroup.ChildrenProperty, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty)
```

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.path.aspx).

Comment: I get another exception  " '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'."